# How to get tuple name without invoking it's items

Tags: python, string, tuples

```
>>> a1=(1,2,3)
>>> a2=(14,5,6)
>>> x1=(a1,a2)
>>> xx=repr(x1)
>>> xx
'((1, 2, 3), (14, 5, 6))'
>>> xxx=str(x1)
>>> xxx
'((1, 2, 3), (14, 5, 6))'
```

Actually, I wanna get from x1 for

```
('a1','a2')
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Well, you just typed it in the first place, so just type what you actually want instead.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: You can't. You can use xx=('a1','a2'), but it will store two string into xx.

Answer (score 2):

```
x1 = ('a1', 'a2')
```

That doesn't make any sense though. Neither does your question - variables in Python are labels for objects. But there is no way to find the name of those labels (i.e. the name of the variables) - here's a good example proving why this would not make any sense:

```
a1 = a2 = (1, 2, 3)
print some_magic_function(a1)
print some_magic_function(a2)
```

In both cases the function will receive the exact same object - so there is simply no way to determine if `a1` or `a2` was passed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a dictionary?

```
>>> a1=(1,2,3)
>>> a2=(14,5,6)
>>> x1=dict(a1=a1,a2=a2)
>>> x1
{'a1': (1,2,3), 'a2': (14,5,6)}
>>> tuple(x1)
('a1', 'a2')
```

Answer (score 0):

As other said, you cannot get the labels of your variables, as they are part of the namespace in which the object is defined, and not the object itself.
For instance, if you define:

```
>>> a = 1
```

It wouldn't make sense to say that all '1' in the world have label `a`. It is just a way a reference in the namespace for `1`, but not a property of the object.

If you need the name, you can of course make it part of the object itself, as a dictionary as Eric suggested, or by subclassing tuple:

```
>>> class _T(tuple):
...     def __new__(cls, name, *args):
...         self = tuple.__new__(cls, args)
...         self.name = name
...         return self
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return self.name

>>> def Tuple(s):
...     return lambda *args: _T(s, *args)

>>> x = (Tuple('a1')(1, 2, 3), Tuple('a2')(4,5,6))
>>> print repr(x)
(a1, a2)
>>> x[0][1] # These are still tuples
2
```

Or some other metaclass manipulation to get as close to what you want as you can, but you cannot escape making the name part of the state of the object, one way or another. Labels are just an interpreter thing, not an object property.